# How to send emails using mailchimp php

Tags: php, email, mailchimp

I am Developing a site and want to send emails using mailchimp email function or using mailchimp mailer. I have custom email template for mails and just want to use mailchimp mailer function instead of php mail(). Is that possible to send my site's email using mailchimp php ?

I cann't do this with list subscribe because i have to use my own email template containing dynamic content. I just want to use mailchimp mail function to send emails of my site instead of php mail().

Here is the code example which i found while searching but didn't work for me

The code returns me nothing, not even an error or warning.
When I echo `Status = ".$data->status."\n"` it display only `Status =`. And if i use print_r($data), it displays blank.

```
$apikey = 'api_key';

            $to_emails = array('rohith038@gmail.com');
            $to_names = array('You', 'Your Mom');

            $message = array(
                'html'=>'Yo, this is the <b>html</b> portion',
                'text'=>'Yo, this is the *text* portion',
                'subject'=>'This is the subject',
                'from_name'=>'Me!',
                'from_email'=>'verifed@example.com',
                'to_email'=>$to_emails,
                'to_name'=>$to_names
            );

            $tags = array('WelcomeEmail');

            $params = array(
                'apikey'=>$apikey,
                'message'=>$message,
                'track_opens'=>true,
                'track_clicks'=>false,
                'tags'=>$tags
            );

            $url = "http://us1.sts.mailchimp.com/1.0/SendEmail";

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'?'.http_build_query($params));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            echo $result;
            curl_close ($ch);

            $data = json_decode($result);
            echo "Status = ".$data->status."\n";
```

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: yes i found some while searching and i tried it but that doesn't work for me.. Kindly check i have updated my Question.

Comment: Why isn't it working? What is going wrong? What errors are you getting?

Comment: This is the issue that above code returns me nothing. not even error or warning. when i echo "Status = ".$data->status."\n";  it display only "Status = ". And if i use print_r($data); it display blank.

Comment: Have you tried to turn on error reporting?

Comment: Yes, Error reporting is on.

Comment: opening http://us1.sts.mailchimp.com/1.0/SendEmail in browser is saying that http://us1.sts.mailchimp.com/ is not available!

Comment: take a look at https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/ for correct url!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get MailChimp API Curl to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560839/cant-get-mailchimp-api-curl-to-work)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.According to the link provided by you my url becomes  $url = "https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/SendEmail"; and it gives me error {"status":"error","code":-32601,"name":"ServerError_MethodUnknown","error":"Unknown method \"\/SendEmail\""}